# Orchestration of services in a SOA using azure VM's

Tags: python-3.x, azure, virtual-machine, soa, orchestration

I am working in a service oriented architecture (SOA) wherein I have a service which takes inputs from the UI and sends out post requests to 2 other microservices & waits for its response to send it back to the UI.

This orchestration can be  handled in kubernetes. But since our team lacks understanding of it we have created azure VM's for this orchestration.

Can someone tell me here if there is a viable way to implement this scenario?
And Can azure VM's be used to orchestrate services?

Comment: It's not the issue for Azur VM, it's the solution which you use to achieve it.

Comment: And what is the go to solution here? Can I use a middleware component such as apache camel here?

Comment: Yes, you can use them in the VM

Comment: @CharlesXu okay.  which azure service other than VM would  you suggest to use?

Comment: So many, Azure Web App, AKS and Azure container instance and so on.